# How to create a function with SQL in Python and create columns?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I´m accessing a Microsoft SQL Server database with pyodbc in Python and I have many tables regarding states and years. I´m trying to create a pandas.DataFrame with all of them, but I don't know how to create a function and still create columns specifying YEAR and STATE for each of these states and years (I'm using NY2000 as an example). How should I build that function or "if loop"? Sorry for the lack of clarity, it's my first post here :/

```
tables = tuple([NY2000DX,NY2001DX,NY2002DX,AL2000DX,AL2001DX,AL2002DX,MA2000DX,MA2001DX,MA2002DX])
jobs = tuple([55,120])

query = """ SELECT
             ID,
             Job_ID,
             FROM {}
             WHERE Job_ID IN {}
            """.format(tables,jobs)

NY2000 = pd.read_sql(query,  server)

NY2000["State"] = NY
NY2000["Year"] = 2000
```

My desirable result would be a DF with the information from all tables with columns specifing State and Year. Like:

| Year | State | ID | Job_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | NY | 13 | 55 |
| 2001 | NY | 20 | 55 |
| 2002 | NY | 25 | 55 |
| 2000 | AL | 15 | 120 |
| 2001 | AL | 60 | 120 |
| 2002 | AL | 45 | 120 |
| ------------ | ------- | -------- | ---------- |

Thanks for the support :)

Comment: Aside, you should not be storing many prefixed and suffixed tables in relational databases. All those tables should be normalized into a *single* table with *state* and *year* indicators. Consider a database design if possible.

Comment: By *SQL Database*, do you mean SQL Server Database? If so or not, please tag your DBMS. FYI: No company including Microsoft owns the *SQL* name.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments about a normalised database and you haven't posted the table structures either. I'm assuming the only way to know year and state is by the table name, if so then you can do something along these lines:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Year":[],"State":[],"ID":[],"JOB_ID":[]})
tables = ["NY2000DX2","NY2001DX","NY2002DX","AL2000DX","AL2001DX","AL2002DX","MA2000DX","MA2001DX","MA2002DX"]
jobs = tuple([55,120])

def readtables(tablename, jobsincluded):
    query = """ SELECT
             {} YEAR,
             {} STATE,
             ID,
             Job_ID,
             FROM {}
             WHERE Job_ID IN {}
            """.format(tablename[2:6],tablename[:2],tablename,jobsincluded)
    return query

for table in tables:
    print(readtables(table,jobs))
    #dftable= pd.read_sql('readtables(table,jobs)', conn)
    #df=pd.concat[df,dftable]
```

please note that I commented out the actual table reading and concatenation into the final dataframe, as I don't actually have a connection to test. I just printed the resulting queries as a proof of concept.